# Class and field level @JsonView annotation and Object Mapper

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-databind, json-view

I have `views` and `entity` class as shown below:

```
class Views{
   class ViewOne{}
   class ViewTwo{}
}

class Test{

   @JsonView({Views.ViewOne.class})
   public int x;

   @JsonView({Views.ViewTwo.class})
   public int y;

   public int z;

   public int v;
}
```

My question is that do I need to have `@JsonView({Views.ViewOne.class, Views.ViewTwo.class})` at class level so that I have non-annotated fields like `z, v` in the output response irrespective of View Class passed to Object Mapper?

I did try to look into different resources regarding the use of **class level `@JsonView` annotation** but I couldn't find any. Does it have any effect? If yes, pls do explain the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Do I need to have `@JsonView({Views.ViewOne.class, Views.ViewTwo.class})` at class level so that I have non-annotated fields like `z`, `v` in the output response irrespective of view class passed to `ObjectMapper`?

You won't need that when [`MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/MapperFeature.html#DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION) is enabled in your `ObjectMapper` instance. This feature is *enabled by default*. May have you disabled it somehow?

Here's a quote from the documentation:

> Feature that determines whether properties that have no view annotations are included in JSON serialization views (see [`@JsonView`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonView.html) for more details on JSON Views). If enabled, non-annotated properties will be included; when disabled, they will be excluded.

---

### Example 1

Let's consider the following `Example` class:

```java
@Data
public class Example {

    private int a = 1;

    private int b = 2;

    private int c = 3;
}
```

And let's serialize an instance of `Example` as a JSON using:

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(new Foo());
```

It will produce the following JSON:

```
{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}
```

---

### Example 2

Now let's take the following views into account:

```java
public class Views {

    public static class Foo {}

    public static class Bar {}
}
```

And let's the apply the views to the fields of the `Example` class:

```java
@Data
public class Example {

    @JsonView(Views.Foo.class)
    private int a = 1;

    @JsonView(Views.Bar.class)
    private int b = 2;

    private int c = 3;
}
```

And let's serialize an instance of `Example` using the `Foo` view:

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String json = mapper.writerWithView(Views.Foo.class).writeValueAsString(new Example());
```

It will produce the following JSON:

```
{"a":1,"c":3}
```

Now let's disable the default view inclusion an serialize it again:

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.disable(MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION);
String json = mapper.writerWithView(Views.Foo.class).writeValueAsString(new Example());
```

It will produce the following JSON:

```
{"a":1}
```

---

### Example 3

Now let's use the following view configuration in the `Example` class:

```java
@Data
@JsonView(Views.Foo.class)
public static class Example {

    private int a = 1;

    @JsonView(Views.Bar.class)
    private int b = 2;

    private int c = 3;
}
```

And let's serialize an instance of `Example` using the `Foo` view:

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String json = mapper.writerWithView(Views.Foo.class).writeValueAsString(new Example());
```

It will produce the following JSON:

```
{"a":1,"c":3}
```

Now let's serialize an instance of `Example` using the `Bar` view:

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String json = mapper.writerWithView(Views.Bar.class).writeValueAsString(new Example());
```

It will produce the following JSON:

```
{"b":2}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I also read about it and found out that by-default it's enabled and so all properties not explicitly marked as being part of a view, are serialized. But then what's the use of **class-level** `@JsonView` annotation(I mean `@JsonView` written above class Name). I was under the impression that I am getting non-annotated fields in my response due to that. But now I have removed it as and it's still working because of DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION enabled by-default.So that's not the use case for class-level `@JsonView` annotation. Could you pls let me know ur thoughts on this?

Comment: @YugSingh Since Jackson 2.9, `@JsonView` can be used on classes (see the [release notes](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson/wiki/Jackson-Release-2.9)) to specify the _default view_ to use on non-annotated properties. This behavior can be overridden by `@JsonView` at property-level. Also see this [issue in GitHub](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/507), which requested this feature.

Comment: Thanks again for the above info. I did refer to the release notes as well as the issue in github. What I understood is class-level JsonView annotations used to specify the default view for non-annotated attr. which means when we specify the default view class only then we will get the non-annotated attributes along with all the annotated attributes(if any with that particular default view class). Pls let me know If my understanding is correct.

Comment: I just tried it. First I got **DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION** disabled. After that I have class-level @JsonView annotations. Now when I am getting the response I can't see the non-annotated attributes at all. If I enable DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION then it works properly. It looks like class-level jsonview has no effect.

Comment: @YugSingh I've added some examples to my answer. Hope it clarifies the `@JsonView` usage.